# Saving Amazon Cognito user credentials without local storage

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I'm using Amazon Cognito for user login for a website with the Javascript SDK which uses local storage to save the user's credentials which are used for things like auto login. This doesn't work when running from a local file on your computer.

Is it possible to direct the Javascript SDK to save user credentials through some other means instead of local storage when running a website locally?

I've seen references to changing the storage object but I can't find any samples on how to actually implement a custom storage solution.
https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/pull/363

Comment: I know this doesn't necessarily answer your question, but why not just provide a lightweight server to serve the site up locally over `localhost`? Would your application usually be downloaded by end users and run directly from a file? It _sounds_ like you're needing this for testing and development, and serving up the file over `localhost` would more closely match your end user's experience.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The issue is the HTML file is being served in an Adobe Extension where local storage isn't available but you have the same issue if you load a local file using a browser like Safari.

Answer (score 4):

## To answer your exact question

As shown in the [pull request you linked](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/pull/363) to you can now specify a [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) object for the pool to use. There are two built in Storage objects according to MDN: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). You may be able to use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) as is (I haven't tried it). It will survive page reloads but is cleared when the page/tab is closed. New tabs get a new [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) object.

```
let pool = new CognitoUserPool({ 
  UserPoolId, 
  ClientId, 
  storage: window.sessionStorage 
});
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to build an object that implements the [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) API. It's pretty simple and would not take much to do. There are 5 total methods and most can be mapped 1:1 with a simple `Object`

```
Storage.key(int n); // Return the Nth key
Storage.getItem(string key) // return the value for given key
Storage.setItem(string key, string value) // store a value at key
Storage.removeItem(string key) // remove the value for key
Storage.clear() // delete all values
```

Here is an NPM package that implements the [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) API in [memory](https://github.com/Download/memorystorage). Downside is that page refreshes would clear it.

As you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/Download/memorystorage/blob/master/src/memorystorage.js) it's not very complicated.

## However

In my opinion a better alternative would be to use a very simple server like [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) or a [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en) to serve the files over http so that [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (and many other parts of the page) work as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! This almost works but Cognito is only calling my `getItem` function. Once I login and call `setDeviceStatusRemembered` it's not calling any of my other custom storage functions like `setItem` to store the credentials. Is there another step I'm missing?

Comment: @BerryBlue I just did some digging in the https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js source code and the storage object can be passed on creation of the CognitoUserPool object. This looks to be important because the `pool.storage` reference is copied to user objects.

Even more fascinating is that it already has a built-in memory storage fallback. https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/StorageHelper.js The gist of it is `try window.localStorage on failure, use memory storage`.

That begs the question, why does't that work in your case?

Comment: @BerryBlue Where  you able to try passing the storage object as part of the CognitoUserPool init?

Comment: I took another look at the storage helper in the [AWS SDK code](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/blob/master/src/StorageHelper.js#L73) and noticed that it's only calling setItem and removeItem to test if `window.localStorage` is a viable option. It doesn't actually check that the functions work, just that they do not throw an error. Have you done any tests in your Adobe Extension to see what parts of localStorage don't work? Is `window.localStorage === undefined`? or is it defined but non-functional? Not sure what extension you're using so cannot easily test myself.